# Accessing Database Objects Using HTTP

Tags: sql-server, http

Is it possible to access database object using HTTP in `SQL Server 2012` the way it was done using `SQL Server 2000`?

I referred following article but it is about `SQL Server 2000`.

[Accessing Database Objects Using HTTP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226552(v=sql.80).aspx)

I want to access the database object in following manner

```
http://iisserver(my machine ip)/nwind/dbobject/Test4[@Id='1']/@x
```

Comment: Why on earth would you directly expose an entire database over HTTP? Anyway, look at OData and WCF Data Services.

Comment: well its the intranet purpose (as of now)...just an R&D which I am doing right now... for my application WCF is out of question because the client which will be using this url is not a windows platform

Comment: That's the point of a WCF service: it doesn't matter what kind of client connects to it.

Comment: will it work on PIC Micro-controller  platform?

Comment: Again: it doesn't matter what kind of client connects to it. Host WCF on Windows, consume using SOAP / OData / REST / ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx#BKMK_ssde, the SQL server can be configured to be accessed via HTTP. To achieve this you firstly need to create and endpoint (as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx)). Among this, the *[firewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx)* issue is also need to be checked because of the additional ports usage. But, according to this *[article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707789%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)*, the HTTP endpoints will not be supported in the future versions of SQL Server.