# SQL query from http connection ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to connect to a service via an HTTP connection in SSIS. I have a connection manager that connects to a website using a login and password. I have tested the connection manager and it says that the connection succeeds. From this point, I need to query a database and run a SQL query to obtain the data I need. Once the data is retrieved, I need to update a table on my instance of SQL Server with the data I have retrieved through the web service.

I have the connection established I am just confused as to how I get the query passed and the records returned.

Comment: You can't connect to a SQL instance over an HTTP connection.  The website would need an endpoint (for example, an API) to which you make requests.  It doesn't sound like this is your scenario.  Is the SQL instance on your network?  Or what?

Comment: If the service you connect to allows you to run SQL Queries, you would have to ask the person who created it how to use it.   There's no way anyone here can know.   There is no "standard" way to do it.

Comment: Looks like following thread has answered your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655012/accessing-database-objects-using-http